# Bound on variance of sum of variables

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, bounds

Suppose I have two finite sets of data `A` and `B`, with equal length `n`.

What's the best upper and lower bound I can make on `var(A+B)`, in terms of `var(A)` and `var(B)`?

Comment: This question simplifies greatly when recast in terms of the variances, due to the simple formula for var(A+B).  That version is addressed by the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: Okay, I've now found $var(A+B) \leq var(A) + var(B) + 2 \sqrt{var(A) var(B)}$, but is this bound tight?

Comment: @Greg Snow's example (where $A=B$) demonstrates tightness.

Comment: The upper bound can be written a bit more cleanly in terms of standard deviations $sd(A + B) \le sd(A) + sd(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound will occur when $B = -A$ so that $A + B = 0$ and the variance is $0$.  This also occurs when $B$ is shifted from $A$, but in any case you cannot have a variance less than $0$ and this shows a case where it can equal $0$.

The upper bound comes when $B = A$ or $B = c1 + c2 \times A$ which gives a correlation of $1$.  In this case you get the variance is the comments above.